# Using functions from other shared library in UDF

Tags: c++, mysql

I'm new to UDF and MySQL :-).

I faced the following problem:

I created UDF and compiled to so library (under Linux).
My UDF calls functions from the other shared object (librpm.so).

When issuing 'SELECT FUNCTION()' with my UDF it returns:
./librpm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Is there a way how to make MySQL load the other .so as well and make it works?

What I checked:

1. I put librpm.so to MySQL plugin directory - didn't help.(the same directory as udf.so)

For now I don't have idea how to resolve it,

Comment: If your library logically depends on a library next to it, consider using the RPATH feature of ELF libraries, accessible via the `-rpath` option to your linker.

Comment: you mean when I want to create UDF.so I have to use -rpath? would you please tell me how?

Comment: @Botje I used this command while creating UDF.so:                                                       gcc -shared -fpic -o UDF.so UDF.cc -Wl,-rpath=/home/.../plugin/librpm.so       but it did not work and the same error came up.

Comment: rpath should point to a directory, not a file

Comment: @Botje my bad type mistake yes I used the path only I mean ...... -rpath=/home/.../plugin and did not work when I create the function and select function in mysql again.